# Does Caliburn.micro simplecontainer supports property injection?

Tags: dependency-injection, caliburn.micro

Does Caliburn.micro simplecontainer supports property injection? How can I do this injection?

Answer (score 1):

Yes via `Bootstrapper.BuildUp()` - just call `container.BuildUp(instance)`

In your bootstrapper:

```
SimpleContainer _container;

protected override void Configure()
{
    _container = new SimpleContainer();

    // Register stuff:
    _container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(IWindowManager), null, typeof(WindowManager));

    base.Configure();
}

// Property inject:
protected override void BuildUp(object instance)
{
    _container.BuildUp(instance);
}
```

Calls to `IoC.BuildUp` in code will pass anything through the `Bootstrapper.BuildUp` method

Answer (score 0):

Yes it supports.

**Property Injection**

Property Injection provides the ability to inject services into an entity created outside of the dependency container. When an entity is passed into the BuildUp method its properties will be inspected and any available matching services will be injected using the same recursive logic as above.

```
...
        var shellViewModel = new ShellViewModel();
        _container.BuildUp(shellViewModel);
    }
}


public class ShellViewModel {
    public IEventAggregator EventAggregator { get; set; }
}
```

In most cases constructor injection is the best option because it makes service requirements explicit, however property injection has many use cases. It is important to note that property injection only works for Interface types.

Source: [Caliburn.Micro Documentation](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/simple-container)